# rails 3 settingslogic uninitialized constant Settingslogic error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, settingslogic

I am trying to set up settings in my app:

in app/models/_settings.rb

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
    source "#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml"
    namespace Rails.env
end
```

in config/app_config:

```
# config/app_config.yml
defaults: &defaults
  global_param: "global"
  awesome_setting: 1 #<%= "Did you know 5 + 5 = #{5 + 5}?" %>

development:
  <<: *defaults
  mongo:
    ip: "localhost"

backoffice:
  <<: *defaults 
  mongo:
    ip: "10.111.144.139"

staging:
  <<: *defaults
  mongo:
    ip: "10.111.144.139"


production:
  <<: *defaults
  mongo:
    ip: "10.111.144.139"
```

in my app/helpers/kanbanFacade.rb row 98:

```
conn = Mongo::Connection.new(Settings.mongo.ip, 27017)
```

still I get this error:
`uninitialized constant KanbanFacade::Settings` (in my app helpers row 98)

why is this happening?

Comment: As an aside, when joining paths/urls it's much better to use `File.join` than interpolation e.g. `File.join(Rails.root,"config/app_config.yml")`. For the main question - have you tried requiring `app/models/_settings.rb` in `app/helpers/kanbanFacade.rb`?

Comment: thanks for the response, I have bypassed the problem by using the `yettings gem`